# Super.Init called multiple times in initializer

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I've been learning spritekit but I'm having some difficulties with super.init. I'm coming from a background of Java and was wondering why I was receiving the error: 
"Super.Init called multiple times in initializer"

What I'm trying to achieve is a constructor that assigns the proper resting texture to the character, while also setting up the texture array so that I can call it without having to worry about passing it values.

I've looked into the documentation but I think my coffee levels are depleted as I really could not make much sense out of why super.init might be calling itself. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated. I did search for similar questions but could not find one, if I was mistaken to post this a link to the answer would be equally appreciated.

```
class CharClass : SKSpriteNode
{

var textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas()
var textureArray = [SKTexture]()

 init() {
    textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named:"Org")
    //likely should be a passed variable instead
    for i in 1 ... textureAtlas.textureNames.count{
        var Name = String();
        if(i<10)
        {
            Name = "cWalk000\(i).png"
        }
        else
        {
            Name = "cWalk00\(i).png"
        }
        textureArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: Name));

        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: textureAtlas.textureNames[0]);
        super.init(texture:texture, color: UIColor.clear, size:texture.size())

        self.size = CGSize(width:71 , height: 131);

        self.position = CGPoint(x: -282.52, y:-141.5);
        self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with: textureArray, timePerFrame: accelSpeed)))

    }




}
```

Comment: The problem is that you are calling `super.init` inside a loop. Don't do that. Only call `super.init` once.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to get some sleep seeing as I forgot to close my loop

Answer (score 1):

rmaddy's answer is correct. Close your `for` loop as you can only call `super.init` once:

```
for i in 1 ... textureAtlas.textureNames.count {
    let name: String
    if(i < 10) {
        name = "cWalk000\(i).png"
    } else {
        name = "cWalk00\(i).png"
    }
    textureArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: name))
}

let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: textureAtlas.textureNames[0])
super.init( texture: texture,
            color:   UIColor.clear,
            size:    texture.size() )
```

Also, welcome to swift :)  Don't forget that `;` is totally optional /thumbsup

Also, it's good to *not* initialize something before attempting to use it. I know that Java forces you to do that, but I changed `var name` to `let name` as it doesn't actually need to be initialized there, nor does it actually need to mutate. You could actually just do:

```
i < 10 ? ( textureArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "cwalk000\(i).png")) ) :
         ( textureArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "cwalk00\(i).png" )) )
```

This will generally speed up your code and saves you 8 lines from your original ;) Just a tip for a new swifter!